SQL - join two tables as many times as there are matches in the first table
Primary table



Name
W
H
D




Primary item 1
100
500
300


Primary item 2
100
600
300


Primary item 3
200
500
300


Primary item 4
100
500
300


Primary item 5
100
600
300


Primary item 6
200
500
300



Secondary table



Name
W
H
D




Secondary item 1
100
500
300


Secondary item 2
100
600
300


Secondary item 3
200
500
300


Secondary item 4
100
500
300


Secondary item 5
100
600
300


Secondary item 6
200
500
300



Result



Name
W
H
D




Primary item 1
100
500
300


Secondary item 1
100
500
300


Secondary item 4
100
500
300


Primary item 4
100
500
300


Secondary item 1
100
500
300


Secondary item 4
100
500
300



W = 100, H = 500, D = 300.
How to write a query so that each row from the first table is supplemented with results from the second?
Is it possible to do this?
Image for for better understanding ↓
color image

Please provide your table structure and example data as DDL statements (ie CREATE TABLE ..., and INSERT INTO ...). But actually I don't think this is possible with pure SQL queries only (might be with stored procedures though)

What DBMS are you using? What do the relevant columns in your tables really look like? Is it really text with a number at the end that defines the relationship? In any case, this feels like it’s mostly a UNION with some sorting.

Yep, always tag SQL requests with your DBMS. I've posted an answer, and despite using standard SQL you may be using a DBMS that doesn't support the syntax.

Select the rows from primary_data that have pairs in secondary_data and union the result with the inner join of primary_data and secondary_data on w, h, d columns.
select name, w, h, d
from ( select
         *,
         name as prim_name,
         1 as is_prim
       from primary_data as p
       where exists( select *
                     from secondary_data as s
                     where s.w = p.w and s.h = p.h and s.d = p.d )
       union all
       select s.*, p.name, 0
       from primary_data as p
       join secondary_data as s
       on s.w = p.w and s.h = p.h and s.d = p.d ) as t
where w = 100 and h = 500 and d = 300
order by prim_name, is_prim desc, name;

db<>fiddle

You want a union of the primary table rows with secondary table rows that match the former. And you want them sorted in a certain way. So, we must use UNION ALL to get the union, and we must build a sortkey. One way to do this:
select name, w, h, d
from
(
  select name, w, h, d, name as sortkey
  from primary_table
  where w = 100 and h = 500 and d = 300
  union all
  select s.name, w, h, d, p.name || '#' || s.name as sortkey
  from primary_table p
  join secondary_table s using (w, h, d)
  where w = 100 and h = 500 and d = 300
) unioned
order by sortkey;


See example.(semantically equivalent @ThorstenKettner answer)
select t.name,w,h,d
from(
  select t1.name,w,h,d, name as key1,'' as key2
  from PrimaryTable t1
  -- where w = 100 and h = 500 and d = 300
  union all
  select t2.name,t2.w,t2.h,t2.d, t1.name as key1, t2.name as key2
  from PrimaryTable t1
  inner join SecondaryTable t2 on t1.w=t2.w and t1.h=t2.h and t1.d=t2.d
  -- where t1.w = 100 and t1.h = 500 and t1.d = 300
) t
order by w,h,d,key1,key2

Ordering by w,h,d is more understandable and visual, if filter WHERE not used.
Demo

Your answer requires an Upvote for sure.
